# display text on hover image - but only on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to display a caption text on image on hover but so that only the image is affected. The way it works now is that the entire div including the button below the image are affected. How can I get the hover effect to affect only he image and leave the buttons unchanged? 
So far I've tried shuffling around the caption divs but with no luck.
Since the image is responsive (not in this example) I can not define an exact height for the `fadeIn_capsFull` class
Any suggestions?

Have a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QL3jD/25/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="product-display fadeIn_caption">
<div class="fadeIn_capsFull">
<div class="capsFull_Text"><h5>PRODUCT ID12</h5><br>$225.00</div>
</div>
<a href="">
<img src="http://placehold.it/400x450" class="product-image" alt="">
</a>
<div class="product-addOptions">
<div class="product-toCart">Add to Cart</div>
<div class="product-toCompare">Add to Compare</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fadeIn_capsFull {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; background:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75) ; width:420px; height:100%;display: table;  display: none; text-align:center; color:#000 !important; z-index:2; cursor:pointer;}
.capsFull_Text { padding-top: 24%; text-align: center; }
.product-display { width:400px; min-height: 400px; padding: 10px; font-size: 13px}
.product-image {margin-bottom:10px; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.product-addOptions { width: 100%; background-color: #0CF;}
.product-toCart { width: 50%; border-right: 1px solid #000; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top:5px; }
.product-toCompare {width: 49%; float:left; text-align:center; padding-top: 5px; }
```

**jQuery**

```
$("[rel='tooltip']").tooltip();    

$('.fadeIn_caption').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeIn(250)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeOut(205)
    }
);
```

Comment: Your <div>s don't look right.  You might want to wrap the image in a div and hover on that.

Comment: please complete your dom where the closing div should be placed

Comment: you are right, one closing div has fallen off in the copy-paste;ing

Comment: question has now been updated to include missing closing div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL3jD/29/).

Checking the height of the image and also the top position to apply to the caption div.

```
$('.fadeIn_caption').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeIn(250)
            .height($(this).parent().find('img').outerHeight(true))
            .css("top", $(this).parent.find('img').offset().top-$(this).parent().offset().top);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeOut(205)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a much simpler method. It does not look very stylish but just works!
Remove all the things you have added for the tool tip text. And now just add whatever you want to show on mouse hover in the title attribute of that element:

```
<element title="Tool tip text you want">...</element>
```

In this case it would be like this:

```
<a href="">
<img title="Tool tip text" src="http://placehold.it/400x450" class="product-image" alt="">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

Try this

```
1. Close the div properly

2. Provide custom min-height for class .fadeIn_capsFull
```

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/QL3jD/26/

I just provide the `min-height` for the class `.fadeIn_capsFull`

Comment: thank you but did you pay attention to this line:
"Since the image is responsive (not in this example) I can not define an exact height for the fadeIn_capsFull class"

Comment: @no0ne, sorry i don't , what about min-height??Is this ok?

Comment: don't know how that would work.. do you have an example?

Comment: @no0ne, i just added min-height, plz look the edited answer and fiddle

Comment: @none make sure it will worked for responsive images and you can make required changes  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code inside hover event handler.
It will set the height of the div based on the height of the image.

```
 $('.fadeIn_capsFull').height($('img').height()+20);
```

so it will be

```
$('.fadeIn_caption').hover(
        function(){

            $('.fadeIn_capsFull').height($('img').height()+20);
            $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeIn(250)
        },
        function(){
            $(this).find('.fadeIn_capsFull').fadeOut(205)
        }
    );
```

Note: +20 is set because of the css file that set margin-bottom:10px, and border, etc.

http://jsfiddle.net/uawG9/

Answer (score -1):

Or if you want to use some jQuery plugin, check [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/30-text-captions-overlay-image-plugins/)